# Problems with Wi-Fi on Debian

Tags: debian, pci, broadcom

Since debian is a second OS on a dual booted mac, there is always problems with Wi-Fi. On this decice, my driver is **BCM43224**, which is supported by the **Broadcom Wl** driver. Upon installation, the Wi-Fi worked perfectly for half a day.

However then, the power cable got disconnected and the mac shutdown forcefully. There was seemingly no data corruption as I could run normally, but the Wi-Fi stopped working once again.

The lsmod command shows wl and a driver that wl uses, and the lines say:

```
Module     Size     Used by
wl               6299053        0
cfg80211  405538          1 wl
```

I also noticed that the wlan0 interface has suddenly disappeared.

I tried removing, and re-adding with `modprobe`, without success, even upon restarting. How can I fix this problem with Wi-Fi?

---

Debian 8 (Jessie) KDE, on a Mac Mini.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ostensibly, the problem got fixed by restoring /etc/network/interfaces back to default. I added a wlan0 in there earlier as it wasnt there before, but wlan0 now also shows in ifconfig